# iOS Google Maps Custom Tiles Overlay

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am wondering if it is possible to create a custom tile overlay in Google Maps SDK for iOS? I have found some examples which uses online tiles from URL, but I would really like to have the tiles boundled with the app (offline). Has anyone done this successfully? I can not seem to find anything online. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can work with Apple's MapKit then you can replace the tiles with your own (there are WWDC videos showing this). But bundling anything above a small number of tiles (regardless of using Google Maps or MapKit) in an app will make the app size enormous.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have successfully hadded the MapBox SDK which does exactly what I want.